# What is the meaning of complex values/multiplicities in dimension spectrum?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, noncommutative-geometry, dimension-theory

If we have a manifold $M$ (say smooth, closed) it can be equipped with the Laplace operator $\Delta$. One can consider the function $\textrm{trace}(\Delta^{-s})$ where $s$ is complex parameter and $\Delta^{z}$ is defined using the Cauchy integral formula. If $\textrm{Re}(s)$ is sufficiently big then the trace does make sense. There is a remarkable result that this trace extends to the meromorphic function with at most simple poles located at $n/2$, $(n-1)/2$, $\ldots$ All the poles are simple, real and the set of poles is discrete. So my question is:

> Are there any interesting examples of spectral triples $(A,H,D)$ with the associated algebra $A$ being commutative such that $\mathrm{trace}(\left|D\right|^{-s})$ extends meromorphically but the set of poles:
>   - contains complex values
>   - contains multiplicities
>   - contains arbitrary big real values
>   - is not discrete, for example contains some interval.